# Want to pick a date for appointment on a website which is not available right now, want to select as soon as its available

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker, selenium-chromedriver

Can anyone help me with the Selenium webdriver (in Python) code to automatically select a date in the input date. I want to select a date when it will be available. Right now the dates are not available and as soon as it will be available, I Want to select it.
Will appreciate any help.

Comment: We would need to see the HTML code first, or in this case link to the page would help us. Also, Update the question with code trial, error stack trace etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebDriverWait` to wait until certain condition is met. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html